# Clean URL's using htaccess breaks my css

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to clean my URL path's so that I don't have any GET parameters and PHP extensions in all of my links. As an example for what I'm trying to achieve:

```
http://localhost/projectname/?page=dashboard
```

needs to be:

```
http://localhost/projectname/dashboard/
```

And it actually works, I used the following code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dashboard/
RewriteRule dashboard/ http://localhost/projectname/?page=dashboard
```

However, the page displays itself without any CSS or Javascript. I tried navigating to my Style.css only to find out that it looks exactly like the webpage itself, instead of showing me my CSS rules.

So what am I doing wrong? Please don't mark my question as a duplicate, I've been looking into similar questions but couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the relative URI when your URL goes from `/projectname/` to `/projectname/dashboard/`.

When that happens, every relative link on the page will have the wrong base added to it. The browser has no idea that the base is actually `/projectname/` when all it sees is the location being at `/projectname/dashboard/`.

Right now, when your css is linked like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/style.css">
```

The browser attempts to resolve it by adding the base from the location, and it'll load:

```
https://localhost/projectname/dashboard/Content/style.css
```

which doesn't exist because the "dashboard" isn't actually a folder.

You can either add a base to the actual page by including this in the page header:

```
<base href="/projectname/" />
```

Or you can try to un-rewrite the dashboard out of the request (a bit trickier and more error prone) by adding this rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/projectname/dashboard/(.*\.css)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/projectname/%1 -f
RewriteCond ^projectname/dashboard/(.*\.css)$ /projectname/$1 [L]
```

Note that does this may have an unintended impact on your browser's cache.

Answer (score 1):

Use the absolute path to the CSS.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/projectname/assets/style.css">`

Comment: I've been learned to never use absolute path's, there must be a better solution.